How to suppress certain C++ linter suggestions in Visual Studio in specific placed in code?
Visual Studio has many useful linter suggestions (I'm using VS2022). But sometimes I should not follow the suggestion and would like to suppress it, in certain places. As a contrived example:
class FooContainer
{
    Foo* foo;
public:
    const Foo* GetFoo() const { return foo; } //OK
    Foo* GetFoo() { return foo; } //Suggestion: The member function can be made const
}

Here I don't want to break const correctness by allowing nonconst access to a Foo through a const FooContainer. It seems like the suggestion is here because the function does not modify the FooContainer so, from the compiler's perspective, it could be const. But logically, this function should not be const.
I don't want to turn this off everywhere, but for this specific function I would like to turn it off. I couldn't find anything on Google. Is there a way?

I typed "msdn visual studio c++ analyze warning disable" into my search engine and came up with Suppress code analysis violations and No option to suppress C++ code analysis warning that seemed interesting.  Always search the internet before posting to StackOverflow; if you have, indicate your results.

I did search before asking, sorry for not making that clear. I could not find any relevant answers though. And the links you provided do not provide any solutions to this problem.

It is provided by C++ linter option:  member function can be made const
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/cpp-linter-overview?view=msvc-170#configure-the-linter

for this specific function turn it off

However currently there is no such option:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-support-for-excluding-files-from-intellisenser/406303

OK, so it isn't "code analysis" but actually the "C++ linter". Thanks for the clarification. I don't want to exclude an entire file though, just this specific function. But now that I know better what to search for, it seems there is just no way to do this atm: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-Linter-is-missing-suppression-suppor/10375696

I have the same problem. Especially with OnUpdateUI methods. These cannot be made constant because otherwise the integration into the message map is not possible.
My workaround is the following:
ifdef _DEBUG
#   define Declare_TheMemberFunctionCanBeMadeConst INT_PTR m_countLinter {}     
#   define Linter_TheMemberFunctionCanBeMadeConst ++m_countLinter
#else
#   define Declare_TheMemberFunctionCanBeMadeConst 
#   define Linter_TheMemberFunctionCanBeMadeConst 
#endif 

MyDialog.h
class MyDialog : public CDialog
{
...
  Declare_TheMemberFunctionCanBeMadeConst;
  afx_msg void OnUpdateFunction(CCmdUI* pCmdUI);
...
}

MyDialog.cpp
void MyDialog::OnUpdateFunction(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
   Linter_TheMemberFunctionCanBeMadeConst;
   pCmdUI->Enable(MyConstFunction());
}

If it becomes possible in the future to give hints to the linter then the code can be quickly adapted.
